# Defining Custom GroupBy Aggregation Function Using Pandas Results in an AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame -

```
data = {'year':[1990, 1990, 1990, 
                1990, 1990, 1990, 
                1990, 1990, 1990], 
        'zip':['22204', '22204', '22204',
               '20194', '20194', '20194', 
               '24060', '24060', '24060'],
        'education':[0, 0, 1,
                     1, 0, 1, 
                     0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

And I would like to calculate the percent of each outcome in the education variable `education` using the groupby function -

```
df = df.groupby(['zip', 'year'])['education'].value_counts(normalize = True, dropna = False).unstack().fillna(0)
```

However, I would like to call the line of code within a custom aggregation function. When I run the lines of code below, I get this error message - `AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels'`.

```
def percent_by_category(group):
    return group.value_counts(normalize = True, dropna = False).unstack().fillna(0)
df = df.groupby(['zip', 'year']).agg({'education':percent_by_category})
```

Is it possible to create a custom aggregation function that calculates the percent of each outcome on the groupby groups? Ideally, I would like to call several other built-in and custom aggregation functions. For example -

```
df = df.groupby(['zip', 'year']).agg({'education':percent_by_category,
                                      'education':sum, 
                                      'education':another_custom_function, 
                                       another_variable:another_custom_function})
```

Comment: The problem in your function is you are using `value_counts` as a function that takes no `self` or is not referred to any data. In any case, you should try `return group.value_counts(...)` because also, you are making the function take a parameter which you are never using it inside the function.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1):

No, if use `agg` function is necessary scalar output of aggregation function.

If test how working `.value_counts()`, there are Series, so not possible `unstack` them.

```
def percent_by_category(group):
    print (group.value_counts(normalize = True, dropna = False))

df = df.groupby(['zip', 'year']).agg({'education':percent_by_category})
print (df)
1    0.666667
0    0.333333
Name: education, dtype: float64
0    0.666667
1    0.333333
Name: education, dtype: float64
0    0.666667
1    0.333333
Name: education, dtype: float64
           education
zip   year          
20194 1990      None
22204 1990      None
24060 1990      None
```

So if want return non scalar output it raise error:

```
def percent_by_category(group):
    return group.value_counts(normalize = True, dropna = False)

df = df.groupby(['zip', 'year']).agg({'education':percent_by_category})
print (df)
```

> ValueError: Function does not reduce